# How to set dynamic value to input type="text" like select drop-down from magento 2 admin block class?

Tags: magento-2.1, blocks, backend, adminform

I have custom module for admin where in block there is form.
I want to set dynamic value to input type="text" but not able to set.
Please, see my snippet below:

```
    $fieldset->addField(
                    'category_code', 'text', ['name' => 'category_code','value'=>'11', 'label' => __('Category Code'), 'title' => __('Category Code'), 'required' => true]
            );    
            }else{
            $fieldset->addField(
                    'category_code', 'text',['name' => 'category_code1', 
                          'value'=> $this->vendorAutoCode(),
                        'label' => __('Category Code'), 'title' => __('Category Code'), 'required' => true]
            );    
            }
public function vendorAutoCode(){
         //str_pad(rand(0,9999), 5, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
      return  str_pad(rand(0,9999), 5, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
    }
```

Comment: @Teja bhagavan Kollepara sir, Could you please guide me on same.

Answer (score 0):

After digging in code solution like:

```
    if ($model->getId()) {
                $fieldset->addField('category_id', 'hidden', ['name' => 'category_id']);
                  $fieldset->addField(
                        'category_code', 'text', ['name' => 'category_code', 'label' => _('Category Code'), 'title' => _('Category Code'), 'required' => true])
                        ->setAfterElementHtml('<script>
                                document.getElementById("vendorcategory_category_code").setAttribute("disabled","disabled");

                                    </script>');
            }else{                  
                $fieldset->addField(
                        'category_code', 'text', ['name' => 'category_code', 'label' => _('Category Code'),'class' => 'category_code_disabled', 'title' => _('Category Code'), 'required' => true]);

                $model->setCategoryCode($this->vendorAutoCode());
            }
public function vendorAutoCode(){
        return str_pad(rand(0,9999), 5, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT); 
}
```